# PHP: convert string to float (only if string represents a float)

Tags: php, string, type-conversion

I have an unknwon string that *could* resemble a float. In that case I want to convert it to float (for calculations), otherwise leave it as a string.

**How do I detect if a string *represents* a float number?**

```
$a = "1.23";        // convert $a to 1.23
$b = "1.2 to 1.3";  // leave $b as is
```

Automatic [string conversion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) would convert the latter to `1.2`, but that's not what I want.

Comment: What about just `1`?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function to check variable which might contain a number.
For example:

```
$a = "1.23";
if (is_numeric($a)) {
    $a = (float)$a;
}

$b = "1.2 to 1.3";
if (is_numeric($b)) {
    $b = (float)$b;
}

var_dump([
    'a' => $a,
    'b' => $b
]);
```

Output

> array (size=2)   'a' => float 1.23   'b' => string '1.2 to 1.3'
>   (length=10)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following to check if a string is a float:

```
$a = "1.23";
$isFloat = ($a == (string)(float)$a);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function StrToFloat($var){
    if(is_numeric($var)){
        return (float)$var;
    } else return $var;
} 

$a = "1.23";        // convert $a to 1.23
$b = "1.2 to 1.3";  // leave $b as is

$a = StrToFloat($a); // $a = 1.23
$b = StrToFloat($b); // $b = "1.2 to 1.3"
```

Comment: Actually the same like @Maxim's answer, only nicely wrapped inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

Because it hasn't been mentioned

```
if(preg_match('/^\d+\.\d+$/', $string)){
   $float = (float)$string;
}
```

I think `is_numeric` is a better choice, but this works too.

What I have above only matches floats, so they have to have the decimal. To make that optional use `/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/` instead.

- `^` start of string
- `\d+` one or more digits
- `\.` the dot, literally
- `\d+` one or more digits
- `$` end of string

For the second one `/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/` it's the same as the above except with this addition:

- `(...)?` optional capture group, match this pastern 0 or 1 times.

Which it should now be obvious is what makes the decimal optional.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you would like to use the [non-locale-aware floatval function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.floatval.php):

> `float floatval ( mixed $var )` - Gets the float value of a string.

Example from the documentation:

```php
$string = '122.34343The';
$float  = floatval($string);
echo $float; // 122.34343
```

Comment: I don't see how this works. `floatval($string) == $string` seems to be always true.

Comment: normally it only return a float (0 if its not numeric and the value of the float) but by rereading your post I realize that the `$b = "1.2 to 1.3"` will also return `1.2`sorry